# Tkinter widgets are in the same row, but why aren't they appearing that way?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I am trying to make a start menu for a search engine. I am trying to have buttons and other widgets appear next to labels. This is my code:

```
class Application(tk.Tk): #subclass Tk
    '''Does most of the handling.'''
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.title("Academic Search")
        self.geometry("1000x600")
        self.resizable(width=True,height=True)
        self.start = Start(self)
        self.start.grid(sticky=(tk.E + tk.W + tk.N + tk.S))
        self.update_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Update Database", command=self.to_database)
        self.update_button.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=tk.W)
        self.cc_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Find Common Citations",command=self.to_cc)
        self.cc_button.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.W)#, pady=20)
        self.search_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Search", command=self.search)
        self.search_button.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=(tk.E))


class Start(tk.Frame): #subclass of Frame
    '''The start window'''
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs): #takes same args as parent
        '''Initializes start window.'''
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs) #calls superclass constructor
        query = tk.StringVar()
        self.num_return = tk.IntVar()
        cw = tk.DoubleVar()
        cd = tk.IntVar()
        graph = tk.BooleanVar()
        jstor = tk.BooleanVar()
        self.mb_text = tk.StringVar()
        self.mb_text.set('Search multiple DOIs')
        self.num_return = tk.IntVar()
        self.search_box = ttk.Entry(parent, text='Enter one DOI:',textvariable=query)
        self.multiple_button = ttk.Button(self, textvariable=self.mb_text,command=self.to_mult)
        self.lbl = ttk.Label(self,text='Enter one DOI.')
        self.num_return_lbl = ttk.Label(self, text='Maximum number of records returned:')
        self.num_return_box = ttk.Entry(parent, textvariable=self.num_return)
        self.cw_lbl = ttk.Label(self, text='Citation weight (must be between 0 and 1):')
        self.cw_box = ttk.Spinbox(parent, from_=0, to=1, increment=0.01,textvariable=cw)
        self.cd_lbl = ttk.Label(self, text='Maximum citation distance (runtime will increase dramatically if greater than 3):')
        self.cd_box = ttk.Spinbox(parent, from_=1, to=10,increment=1, textvariable=cd)
        self.jstor_button = ttk.Checkbutton(parent, text='Use JSTOR (requires JSTOR Labs token)',command=jstor)
        self.graph_box = ttk.Checkbutton(parent, text='Graph', variable=graph)
        self.add_widgets()

    def add_widgets(self):
        '''Adds widgets to grid.'''
        self.lbl.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=tk.E)
        self.cw_lbl.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=tk.E)
        self.cw_box.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=tk.E)
        self.cd_lbl.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=tk.E)
        self.cd_box.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky=tk.E)
        self.num_return_lbl.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky=tk.E)
        self.num_return_box.grid(row=5, column=2, sticky=tk.E)
        self.search_box.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=(tk.E+tk.W))
        self.graph_box.grid(row=6, column=2, sticky=tk.E)
        self.jstor_button.grid(row=7, column=2, sticky=tk.E)
        self.multiple_button.grid(row=9, column=0, sticky=(tk.W+tk.N))
```

Why aren't the labels in line with the other elements (Spinboxes, check buttons, entries) when they are in the same row?

This is what it looks like when I do `mainloop()`:

[image: screenshot of mainloop() running]

Comment: It would really help if you reduced this down to a [mcve]. If the problem is with two widgets not aligning, all we need are those two widgets and enough additional code to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The buttons and the labels have different parents, which is why they appear in different locations.

You can see this very clearly if you give the `Start` frame a distinctive color. For example, change how you create `Start` to be like this:

```
self.start = Start(self, background="red")
```

You will end up with a window that looks like this:

[image]

Look at the first argument in each of these two lines of code. One uses `self` and one uses `parent`. `self` and `parent` are two different widgets.

```
    self.cw_lbl = ttk.Label(self, ...)
    self.cw_box = ttk.Spinbox(parent, ...)
```

Everywhere you use `parent` as the parent of a widget in `Start`, you should change it to `self`. For example, the above code needs to be changed to:

```
self.cw_box = ttk.Spinbox(self, ...)
```

Comment: The labels are supposed to be next to the elements on the right though, and they all have the same parents.

Comment: @Firestarter: they appear to have different parents to me: `self.search_box = ttk.Entry(parent,...)` and `self.lbl = ttk.Label(self,..)`.

Comment: Oh I thought you meant the frames. If they have different parents then how do I align them? Or can it not be done?

Comment: @Firestarter: If you want to use `grid` to align them, the practical solution is to have them in the same frame. What's the point of putting them in different frames if you want them to line up in a grid?

Comment: The labels and almost every other element except for the 'Search' button are all in the same frame, and even when I remove the elements that are in another frame it still looks like that.

Comment: @Firestarter: Look again. All of your labels are in a different frame than all of your inputs. This is easy to visualize. Add the following inside the `__init__` of `Start`: `self.configure(background='red')`. You'll see quite clearly that the labels are in a different frame than the other widgets.

Comment: I did that and now I see what you mean! but I'm adding them all in the same frame. How do I get them all to have the same parent?

Comment: @Firestarter: you're passing in the parent as the first argument. Don't pass in `parent`, pass in `self`.

Comment: I got it! Thank you so much!